# using angular 5 for new project

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular-material, angular5, ng-bootstrap

I am using angular 5 for my new project. and as it is said that jQuery is not recommended for angular-5, i am using ng-bootstrap which do not require 3rd party libraries. I am also using angular-material. I have following problems faced.

1. There is No documentation for table in ng-bootstrap.
2. If i use angular material, for tabs there are no more options for customising tabs the way i want. Only restricted options are available.
   If i use both ng-bootstrap and angular-material, i feel unecessarily complexity will be increased.
   if i use any one of them 1st and 2nd problem will not be solved.

i don't have proper documentation for problems i am facing.

Comment: just use normal bootstrap instead of a plugin?

Comment: normal bootstrap uses jquery.. but jquery is not recommended in angular5. which created my confusion.

Comment: no, only the js part of bootstrap uses jquery, the css doesnt

Answer (score 0):

Based on my own experience:

Angular-material is not mature enough for a serious project. Go with ng-bootstrap (not native bootstrap), and in case you need to work with tables, go with an additional table lib for angular like https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable